# Restrict Internet connection flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, manifest

I have added a library into my flutter app, but unfortunately that library start showing pop ups on my screen when the internet connection is available.

I can not edit into the library because its .aar from android. However I can only delete the internet permission from manifest file but the problem is I am using chats in my app so I need internet access for those.

I want to disable the internet access at that particular screen or for that library.
Please let me know how would I achieve that in flutter.

Comment: If you have used a closed source library and it doesn't do what you want, you either need to get the creator of the library to change it or find another library.

Comment: Can we not restrict the app from internet usage programatically?

Comment: Well, you can simply not access the internet from your code, but there is no way your app can simply say "don't let me access the Internet". If you are using code you didn't write then you can't change what it does.

Comment: Note that I'm responding from an iOS point of view. I note that your question mentions .aar. If you are only asking about Android then you should remove the iOS tag